# Levantar libreria (jar) en un classpath específico

Tags: java, tomcat, jar

me gustaría hacerles una pregunta, soy nuevo en Tomcat y java. Y en la empresa tenemos una aplicación que funciona con Tomcat y con unas librerías que se han creado en el equipo. Revisando el funcionamiento tenemos dos librerías (jar) (Librería 1 y Librería 2). Pero la librería 1 tiene dependencia la librería 2.

Las dos están en el CATALINA_HOME/lib. El tema es que cuando actualizamos la librería 2, nos dimos cuenta de que el Tomcat estaba ocupando la dependencia de la librería 1 (que estaba desactualizada).

Entonces mi pregunta es la siguiente, existe la posibilidad de obligar al Tomcat a usar una librería específica (en el classpath), cosa que cuando actualicemos la librería 2, se modifiquen todas?

Cabe mencionar que la librería 2 (que vive en la librería 1) es parte del jar de la librería 1.

Saludos y muchas gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: Hola Miguel. ¿realmente es necesario que ambas librerias esten el tomcat? ¿no pueden formar parte de la aplicación? ¿que versión de Tomcat manejas?

Comment: ¿Qué siginifica "Tomcat estaba ocupando la dependencia de la librería 1"? Si Lib2 es parte de lib1 entonces debeis actualizar Lib1 en el directorio lib del servidor. Y, obviamente, debeis reiniciar.

Answer (score 0):

La versión de Tomcat que tenemos es 7.0.75. Y lo que ocurre es que no queríamos actualizar todos los jar de la aplicación por este cambio, pero al parecer es la única manera.

Saludos!

Comment: Miguel, si este comentario tiene informacion relevante sobre tu pregunta , te recomiendo que edites tu pregunta y la añadas, así los proximos usuarios lo tendran mas facil al leer tu pregunta